# flutter drag down menu

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-layout

I have to make flutter page where at top there is a drag down button or slider so we can view name of the user and in main screen there is a simple button.
If anyone can give me a sample code that how to make a slide down menu in flutter.it will be really useful for me.

Comment: What you want exactly? Something like this? - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theiskaa/field_suggestion/develop/example/assets/default.gif

Comment: yes Something like this,

Comment: I need three drop down buttons in a form with completely different data sets in flutter.If you know how to do this kindly let me know. Thank you.